# Boot camp no osx partition

Tags: bootcamp, partition

So some time ago i used boot camp to install Windows 8 pro.
Now i want to switch back to my mac/osx but there is no osx partition

Screenshot of boot camp on windows: (Ingore the langauge, it's in Danish)

[image]

I have searched around for an answer but i can't find one.

Thanks for reading

**Note 1**
I have tried ALT at the start-up of the computer but there is now OSX disc. Only a windows one. And i have tried to reinstall OSX on one of the discs, but i gives me a error (Can't remember the error, but i couldn't delete the disc either)

Comment: like aaronk6 mentioned please boot into the recovery mode with alt-r, start Utilities/Terminal, enter "diskutil list" & "diskutil cs list" and add the outputs to your question

Comment: did you try the cmd-r boot to restore OS X ?

Comment: @user3527883 sorry command-r and not alt-r

Answer (score 1):

Try holding down the <kbd>alt</kbd> key while powering on your Mac. This should yield a boot device selection.

If this doesn’t help, try booting in Recovery Mode as outlined here: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4718
There you can run Disk Utility to check wether your partition is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

That's an old bug in the BootCamp prefs.

Just reboot and hold the <kbd>alt</kbd> key to get to the boot menu.

Then choose your Mac OS X partition to boot into Mac OS X.